# 変数 b が指すリストを代入した変数 a の順序を変更すると、変数 b のリストまで変更されてしまう

Tags: python

`b`をランダムにしないよう、わざわざ`a=b`をしているのに、なぜか`i`がランダムに表されます。

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = b
for i in b:
    random.shuffle(a)
    c = a
    print(i)
#1,4,5,2,7,3,6
```

当たり前ですがrandomをコメント化すると順通り表示されます。

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a = b
for i in b:
    # random.shuffle(a)
    c = a
    print(i)
#1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

for分の`b`すなわち`i`を妨害しないためには、どうすればよいでしょうか。
python 3.5.2です。

Comment: 例えば、`print(id(a), id(b))` を実行してみると a と b のオブジェクトIDが同じであることが分かるかと思います。この場合、1次元リストですので`a = b[:]` としても良いかと思います(リスト自身のコピー)。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

リストのコピーは

```
a = b[:]
```

とするのが一般的なイディオムです。

```
a = list(b)
```

とする方法もあります。もちろんcopyでもできますが、intのコピーなら大鉈を振るうこともないかと。

追記：コメントに「本来bにはdictの二重配列が入るためその方法`a=b[:]`は使用できませんでした。」と重要な追加がありました。質問本文が編集されるまではこの回答は残しておきます。

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.python.jp/3.5/library/copy.html

> Python において代入文はオブジェクトをコピーしません。

bの要素を気にせずbを保持する場合は`a = b`の代わりに以下のように浅いコピーを行って下さい。

```
a = b.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

コピーを作成したい場合、
`a = copy.copy(b)`
のようにします。

[copy](http://docs.python.jp/3/library/copy.html?highlight=copy#module-copy)